# W3TOTAL CACHE : Disk Enhanced Vs Disk Basic

Tags: wordpress, caching, w3-total-cache

Regarding the w3total cache working mechanism,
I searched the internet but couldnt find any proper information regarding these two.
What is the difference between the disk enhanced and disk basic in w3Total cache.And why is disk enhanced preferred over disk basic?
What the advantages and disadvantages of using the options disk enhanced and disk cache repectively?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Basic - invokes a PHP script, similar to the standard wp-cache plugin.

Enhanced - avoids invoking any PHP script, instead it modifies the .htaccess file to direct Apache2 to a static (cached) version of the resource.

[Source](http://blog.loadimpact.com/tag/w3-total-cache/)

Comment: Source link is broken, but this one may work: http://blog.loadimpact.com/blog/wordpress-load-test-part-2-amendment/